# Issue with Asynchronous Video Processing and New Window Creation in Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I have a Windows Forms application that uses FFmpeg for video processing tasks. In this application, I have a textBox2_TextChanged event handler that performs some video processing tasks based on user input.

However, I noticed that when textBox2_TextChanged is called, the UI becomes unresponsive, and it seems like another window is being created but doesn't show up. I suspect that this issue is related to threading.

Here's a simplified version of the problematic code:

```
// Relevant code snippet:
private async void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0 && int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out int itemvalue) && int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int ratio))
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Video processing code using FFmpeg (e.g., creating thumbnails).
            // This code seems to cause the UI to freeze and prevent new windows from showing up.
        });
    }
}
```

Expected Behavior:

When a user enters a valid input in textBox2, the video processing tasks should be executed in the background without freezing the UI. The application should remain responsive, and any new windows, including message boxes or progress dialogs, should show up as expected.

Actual Behavior:

When a user enters a valid input in textBox2, the video processing tasks appear to be running, but the UI becomes unresponsive, and new windows, such as message boxes, do not show up as expected. This makes it challenging to display any progress or error messages to the user during video processing.

Steps to Reproduce:

Open the Windows Forms application.
Add some video files to the list (listBox1) and provide valid input in textBox2.
Observe the UI behavior and any new windows that should be displayed, such as progress dialogs or message boxes.
Additional Notes:

I am using Visual Studio [version] for development.
The application uses FFmpeg for video processing tasks, and I've verified that FFmpeg is functioning correctly.
I've also tried using proper error handling to catch any exceptions, but no exceptions are thrown during the video processing tasks.
Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and enable new window creation during video processing would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks guys my problem got fixed. Should i delete this qestion?

Comment: It is completely up to you if you want to delete your unanswered question. However, if you have an answer, then you can write an answer to your own question.